# How to maintain the PHP GET value on the address bar if I use another GET?

Tags: php

I am passing a variable from page1 to page2 using GET and it's already working. However, I also use another get in the `<select> <option>` on page2 which means when I click an item in the option, the value I get from page1 disappears and becomes undefined since the address bar changes. I want the variable I get from page1 to be compared on SQL where clause. I can't think of a way on how to solve this, I'm not really knowledgeable in PHP, can you help me?

Here is my code(I remove some unnecessary lines): page1

```
<form method="get" action="home.php">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input id="codehe" class="form-control" type="codehe" name="codehe" placeholder="Class Code">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control button" type="submit"> 
 </div>
</form>
```

page2 (this is how i get the value from page1)

```
<?php 
$codehe = $_POST['codehe'];
echo $codehe;
?>
```

The other GET (form) on page2

```
<form method="GET">
 <select id="state" multiple name="state" onchange='if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }'>
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option> 
    <option value="<?php echo $row['subjects'];?>"><?php echo $row['subjects'];?></option> 
 </select>
</form>
```

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
  $str = $_GET["state"];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM classvideo WHERE subjects = '$str' AND linkcode = ''";  
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional way to do things like this (without client-side code) is to put a hidden input in your form on page 2:

```php
<form method="GET">
 <select id="state" multiple name="state" onchange='if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }'>
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option> 
    <option value="<?php echo $row['subjects'];?>"><?php echo $row['subjects'];?></option> 
 </select>
 <!-- Add this line -->
 <input type="hidden" name="codehe" value="<?php echo $_GET['codehe'] %>">
</form>
```